# Django related _set with order_by showing duplicates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-aggregation

With Django 1.7, using following code in my view:

```
driver = get_object_or_404(Driver, id=self.object.id)
cars = driver.car_set.order_by('model__market_date')
for car in cars:  # for testing only
    print car.id  # outputs e.g. 3, 3, 3, 5
```

When I try this, I get duplicate results for cars (e.g. twice car #3), dependent on the amount of models. I don't want this.

However, when I use `cars = driver.car_set.all()`, the duplicate results are not there. But I want my car list to be sorted on `market_date`.

Any pointer on how to fix this? 
I tried with aggregate() and distinct() but that didn't fix the situation unfortunately (or I'm doing something wrong).

My tries with `distinct()`:

- `driver.car_set.order_by('model__market_date').distinct()` causes duplicates
- `driver.car_set.order_by('model__market_date').distinct('model__market_date')` causes duplicates
- `driver.car_set.order_by('model__market_date').distinct('pk')` yields `Exception Value: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`

Comment: I've remove that answer, edit your question and add that you've tried `distinct()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why do you receive duplicate results, because i don't see nothing unnatural in your code.
In case if you want just to receive a list of cars id (without duplicates), you can change your for cycle in this way:

```
cars_id = []                 # creating empty list for cars id with duplicates 
for car in cars:             # for cycle 
    cars_id.append(car.id)   # appends numbers 3, 3, 3, 5 to our list
cars_id = list(set(cars_id)) # making list with unique values using built-in function set()
```

So after you'll have something like this:

```
>>> cars_id
... [3, 5]
```

Comment: there is comment `# for testing only`

Comment: OK, removing the duplicates works by using `set()`, e.g. by `context['cars'] = set(cars)`. +1 for the workaround, but still puzzled why `driver.car_set.order_by('model__market_date').distinct()` still produces duplicates!

Comment: @SaeX, The problem may be hidden in the database, have you looked in there? Check the duplicates inside.